# Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Tags: linking

I have created a component link on page published through SDL Tridion. But getting following error on webpage.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Java.Lang.Throwable: 
 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

ClassPath           : Z:\websites\dev\Preview\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.deployer.Deployer
 com.tridion.ugc.Status
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
 com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
 [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
 com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
 com.tridion.validation.Errors
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

]]>
 (AbstractLink.java:69)
at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.(ComponentLink.java:84)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
  at Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)]]>

Comment: Is your CD license correct, not expired, machine name and processor cores match?

Comment: Your classpath is showing as ` Z:\websites\dev\Preview\bin\bin` ... one too many bins?

Answer (score 7):

This `NoClassDefFoundError` error usually comes in case of any of the following scenario:

- As you have also listed in your question, there are some dependent .jar or .war file which is missing or have wrong path set somewhere (in configs or code)
- Your existing java installation (JDK or JRE) is corrupted (You may check by running java -version client to verify)
- You are missing any Tridion related configuration file (Probably the cd_storage_config) or any change in XML configuration files have made them invalid XML files
- You have wrong/expired/invalid license files for Content Delivery or wrong path of it has been set in the Tridion related configuration files

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest to check logs files & validate your bin/config/cd_licenses.xml file, linking problem usually occurs when you have invalid license file.

You could have following issues in file

1. Machine name not matching with the name in license file
2. License expired
3. No of cores in your system are more than allowed limit in license.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, there are another common scenario, usually if you have configured a common location folder for configuration files. Please check if the application pool user has read access to the license file location.