# DD4T not working locally

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, licensing

I have a DD4T solution which is working on my server machine . But when I run it though my local IIS with same configuration as server , I am getting the following error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

My local system is running in windows 7 enterprise version 
Server is in Windows server 2008 R2.
Both have 2 cpu core and 2 logical processors

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String
>   Url) +958    DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage&
>   page) +994
>   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String
>   PageId) +240    DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.Page(String
>   pageId) +82    DD4T.Web.Mvc.PageController.Page(String pageId)

My cd core log is as follows

> 2014-07-07 02:02:14,648 INFO  StorageManagerFactory -  2014-07-07
>   02:02:14,649 DEBUG StorageConfigurationLoader - Attempt loading
>   default storage configuration file 2014-07-07 02:02:14,663 INFO 
>   LicenseReader - Validating license in license file
>   file:/C:/New%20folder/**/**/en/bin/config/cd_licenses.xml 2014-07-07
>   02:02:14,667 DEBUG LicenseReader - Found license entry for Tridion CD
>   Linking, trying to validate this license key 2014-07-07 02:02:14,671
>   DEBUG LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified,
>   using user.home var: C:\Users\user name 2014-07-07 02:02:14,831 DEBUG
>   LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified, using
>   user.home var: C:\Users\user name 2014-07-07 02:02:14,831 DEBUG
>   LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified, using
>   user.home var: C:\Users\user name 2014-07-07 02:02:14,832 DEBUG
>   LicenseReader - There was no licenseLock Location specified, using
>   user.home var: C:\Users\user name 2014-07-07 02:02:14,832 WARN 
>   LicenseReader - The machine with name is not licensed to
>   use product Tridion CD Linking. If you think you have a license to use
>   this product on this machine, please contact SDL Tridion Customer
>   Support (support@sdltridion.com)
>
> 2014-07-07 02:02:14,837 INFO  StorageManagerFactory -  2014-07-07
>   02:02:14,837 INFO  StorageManagerFactory -
>   ******************************************************************************** 2014-07-07 02:02:14,837 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Checking if
>   product Tridion CD Storage is enabled.... 2014-07-07 02:02:14,837 INFO
>   StorageManagerFactory - Tridion CD Storage is running in limited mode
>
> 2014-07-07 02:02:22,856 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - Setting session
>   timeout to 120000. 2014-07-07 02:02:22,865 INFO 
>   StorageManagerTransactionMonitor - Starting storage transaction
>   monitoring 2014-07-07 02:02:23,751 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory -
>   Default storage provider has caching set to: false 2014-07-07
>   02:02:23,752 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loaded following dao
>   Properties[publication=0, typeMapping=Query, storageId=brokerdb,
>   cached=false] for publication/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / Query /
>   null 2014-07-07 02:02:23,752 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a
>   non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / Query
>   / null 2014-07-07 02:02:23,758 ERROR Query - Unable to Configure for
>   BrokerQuerying, query DAO could not be retrieved
>   com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object for Query
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.getDAOForTypeMapping(FSDAOFactory.java:177)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:450)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:271)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:178)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.broker.querying.Query.(Query.java:45)
>   ~[cd_broker.jar:na] 2014-07-07 02:02:23,774 ERROR Query - Unable to
>   execute Broker Query, no QueryGenerator was initialized 2014-07-07
>   02:02:23,774 DEBUG Query - Query execution has finished in: 0 ms.
>   2014-07-07 02:02:24,039 DEBUG ClaimStore - put:
>   uri=taf:response:cookie:generation, value=true 2014-07-07 02:02:24,039
>   DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore:
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.dotnet.DotNetClaimStore@3b131db5, thread:
>   Thread-5 2014-07-07 02:02:24,039 DEBUG ClaimStore - put:
>   uri=taf:request:uri, value=/favicon.ico 2014-07-07 02:02:24,039 DEBUG
>   ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:full_url, value= 2014-07-07
>   02:02:24,040 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:headers,
>   value={cookie=[Ljava.lang.String;@6403745f,
>   connection=[Ljava.lang.String;@1ecd3c45,
>   host=[Ljava.lang.String;@342fe5cf,
>   accept-language=[Ljava.lang.String;@349893cd,
>   accept=[Ljava.lang.String;@d0f92b5,
>   user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@7968afc5,
>   accept-encoding=[Ljava.lang.String;@47ebecc8} 2014-07-07 02:02:24,040
>   DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies,
>   value={TAFTrackingId=tridion_0db0fa9d-205c-45b9-aefa-664c8d104b47}
>   2014-07-07 02:02:24,040 DEBUG ClaimStore - put:
>   uri=taf:request:parameters,
>   value={CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@5206635b,
>   QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@2165156f} 2014-07-07 02:02:24,040
>   DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={REMOTE_USER=,
>   PATH_TRANSLATED=C:\New folder****\en\favicon.ico, SERVER_PORT=83,
>   SCRIPT_NAME=/favicon.ico, REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1, AUTH_TYPE=,
>   SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:\New
>   folder****\en, REMOTE_HOST=127.0.0.1, SERVER_NAME=localhost,
>   SECURE=false} 2014-07-07 02:02:24,041 DEBUG ClaimStore - put:
>   uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_ae7d1875-c3f3-4228-9794-f15b5a6e06d1
>   2014-07-07 02:02:24,041 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id,
>   value=tridion_0db0fa9d-205c-45b9-aefa-664c8d104b47 2014-07-07
>   02:02:24,041 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes,
>   value={Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore=Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore}
>   2014-07-07 02:02:24,042 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non
>   cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / Query /
>   null 2014-07-07 02:02:24,043 ERROR Query - Unable to Configure for
>   BrokerQuerying, query DAO could not be retrieved
>   com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object for Query
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.getDAOForTypeMapping(FSDAOFactory.java:177)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:450)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:271)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:178)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.broker.querying.Query.(Query.java:45)
>   ~[cd_broker.jar:na] 2014-07-07 02:02:24,043 ERROR Query - Unable to
>   execute Broker Query, no QueryGenerator was initialized 2014-07-07
>   02:02:24,043 DEBUG Query - Query execution has finished in: 0 ms.
>   2014-07-07 02:23:09,587 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current
>   ambient data context: null 2014-07-07 02:23:09,588 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: null

Comment: Based on [this question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2753/46), I don't think the community has seen Windows 7 Enterprise working as a Tridion Content Delivery environment. It might work, but isn't a supported setup. Could you use a virtual setup instead?

Comment: I have a working set up with tridion 2013 and java version 1.7   .Tridion 2011 sp1 is not working with same system. does lib and config change based on tridion version?

Answer (score 4):

This is licensing issue, you seems to be using different Machine's CD license / Wrong license file , Get in touch with SDL for new license.

you can find license @    `applicationDirectory\bin\config\cd_licenses.xml`

you can refer this [answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/6025/could-not-initialize-class-com-tridion-linking-linking/6026#6026) for details.

Comment: I have replaced the lincense file with a new one and getting error Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +514
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1243
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +907
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, Type declaredType, Boolean bLeaf, JavaMethodArguments jargs) +87

Comment: Is this new license for your machine? did you check points in my answer? could you also put detailed error message after changing file. also make sure..“Enable 32-bit application:false” in application pool if your computer is 64 bit. and valid Java version? what is your CMS version?

Comment: +1 to Raj's request to add a detailed error message. With the license issue "solved," it'll be easier to follow new issues either in a separate question or as an addition to the original.

Comment: @user1137 as Alvin said, could you mark is resolved, and raise new question with error details from Log files and details, it would help people to answer it & would help other to later on refer it. or you can  your question and provide more details with proper details.

Comment: thanks Raj. I am using CMS 2011 sp1, Enabled 32 bit application :false in my app pool, java version 1.7, computer is 64 bit. Apart from this I have another dd4t website in CMS 2013 which is working fine with the same license file . This website have different set of lib and config. So my question is , if it is a license issues then how same license is working for other website on same local IIS. please help

Comment: Each Machine has its own CD license. You can not copy license from one machine and use it on another machine. Did you match the machine name in license with your machine name? as per link in my answer,  Secondly in 2011 SP1 java 1.7 is not supported,, please check following link: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/what-versions-of-java-are-supported-and-proven-to-work-for-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1

Comment: Licenses are typically by named server, so the same license on the same machine works.